# Scala multiple type conformance

Tags: scala, type-inference

I have the following code and will like to call a method on top of a class that implements the trait EventTraces[T] and at the same time T should implement the trait Event (e.g as in doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace())

```
trait Event
class ConcreteEvent[T <: Event]
trait EventTrace[T <: Event]
class ConcreteEventTrace[T <: Event] extends EventTrace[T]

val concreteEventTrace : ConcreteEventTrace[ConcreteEvent] = new ConcreteEventTrace(new ConcreteEvent)

def doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace[T <: Event, Z <: EventTrace[T]](eventTrace: Z) {
    println("Action on top of a Any kind of EventTrace of any type of Event")
}
```

However calling `doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace(concreteEventTrace)` gives me the following error:

> Error:(129, 3) inferred type arguments [Nothing,ConcreteEventTrace[ConcreteEvent]] do not conform to method doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace type parameter bounds [T <: Event,Z <: EventTrace[T]]
>     doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace(concreteEventTrace)
>     ^
>
> Error:(129, 38) type mismatch;
>   found   : ConcreteEventTrace[ConcreteEvent]
>   required: Z
>   doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace(concreteEventTrace)
>                                        ^

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Scala can't infer `T` here because it only has `Z` in the arguments (I don't see a reason it *couldn't*, in this case). The obvious way to fix it is `doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace[ConcreteEvent, ConcreteEventTrace[ConcreteEvent]](concreteEventTrace)`. Another, if you don't actually need to be generic in `Z`:

```
def doSomethingOnTopOfAnEventTrace[T <: Event](eventTrace: EventTrace[T])
```

You could also try to use type members instead of generics in `Event` and `EventTrace`.

Comment: it is known type inference issue, see [SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712) with workaround